# Ruby on Rails how to call javascript function from layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I defined a javascript function called `timeout()` in the file
`app/views/download.js.erb`. It polls a certain location in the server to see if a file is ready for download.

Now, I'm running it as a background process so the user should be able to navigate to different parts of the website while the polling function keeps on checking and checking until the file is ready for download and it will give a pop up message to the user.

So I want to run the `timeout()` function wherever the user is at so the checking is constantly running.

I'm thinking about calling this function in `application.html.erb` if `session[:set_download] == 1` (which I set appropriately in the controller). My questions are

1) is `application.html.erb` the right place to call it?

2) `timeout()` is in `app/views/download.js.erb`... so how do I call it in a file like `application.html.erb` (if it is the right place to place the call to `timeout()`)?

thanks!

Comment: You might want to read this article https://codediode.io/lessons/1904-ajaxified-one-page-application-with-rails.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use application.js for placing your code 
2) add //= require download
before require tree